# Best way to retrieve multiple images from .net Web API and populate in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

This is the code I am using to fetch single image. This code runs in loop to populate the image and is working. But sometimes if there is a delay in fetching the image. The application gets stuck in populating data

```
            var resp = await Client.GetAsync(imageUrl);
            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                imageData = await resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            }
```

This is the loop which is calling the download of individual products images:

```
 List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var product in productsList)
            {
                var task = DownloadImage(eImageType.Brand, product);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
```

code to build the image object dynamically

```
        foreach(var brand in brands)
        {
            brand.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                if (brand.ImageData != null)
                    return new MemoryStream(brand.ImageData);
                else
                    return null;
            });
        }
```

Code to show image view in XAMLS

```
              <AbsoluteLayout>
                                            <ffimage:CachedImage Source="blugegb" HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                   DownsampleWidth="180"
                                                   DownsampleUseDipUnits="True"
                                                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                                       VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                                       Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                                            <ffimage:CachedImage Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                                 DownsampleWidth="100"
                                                                 DownsampleUseDipUnits="True"
                                                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.8,.8" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                                       VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                                       Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                                        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you not just handing FFImageLoading the URL instead and let it get the image for you?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Cheesearon, I am trying it at our end. But It would really help if you can share a link to the similar implementation or share FFImageLoading Code Sample to populate multiple images.

Comment: Just bind the `Source` property on `CachedImage` to your URL

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to return the Files as URLs and not as a stream.

Example:

1. Upload your images to let's say azure blob storage
2. Create a table with the information about the files (or save metadata with the file)
3. In your .NET web api build and action that queries all your files.
4. Make sure that the query returns a JSON that has a result at least like this:

   ```
   { name: 'test', url: 'http://yourpathtoyourimage.com/test.png' }
   ```
5. In your Xamarin Application use a plugin or custom logic to show the images by using their URL:

   ```
   <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0">
     <Image.Source>
       <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Url}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
     </Image.Source>
   </Image>
   ```

Comment: Alright, let me check this Nick, this looks like a very feasible solution. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using FFImageLoading then its very simple all you have to do is :

```
  <ffimage:CachedImage Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                             DownsampleWidth="100"
                                                             DownsampleUseDipUnits="True"
                                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.8,.8" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                                   VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                                   Aspect="AspectFit"/>
```

Provide a binding to CachedImage in its source, then directly pass the URL as the binding to the source eg:

```
public string ImageSource {get; set;}
//SomeWhere in your code 
ImageSource="https://images.pexels.com/photos/807598/pexels-photo-807598.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940/abcd.jpg";
```